# ERROR: Insert data into mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

When I add data to Database MySQL it fails.

```
//function add
public function add($name, $director, $cast, $genre,$release,$duration,$thumb,$plot,$another,$reviews,$critic)** {
        $query = "INSERT INTO $this->table_name(name,director,cast,genre,release,duration,thumb,plot,another,reviews,critic) "
                . "Values('$name','$director','$cast','$genre','$release',$duration,'$thumb','$plot','$another','$reviews',$critic)";
        $data = parent::insert($query);
        var_dump($query);
        return $data;
    }

//Add data
$info = new Info_Film();
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $director = $_POST['director'];
    $cast = $_POST['cast'];`enter code here`
    $genre = $_POST['genre'];
    $release = $_POST['release'];
    $duration = $_POST['duration'];
    $thumb = $_POST['thumb'];
    $plot = $_POST['plot'];
    $another = $_POST['another'];
    $reviews = $_POST['reviews'];
    $critic = $_POST['critic'];
    $info->add($name, $director, $cast, $genre,$release,$duration,$thumb,$plot,$another,$reviews,$critic);
}
?>
```

Comment: Try  `$query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . " (name,director,cast,genre,release,duration,thumb,plot,another,reviews,critic) "  . "Values('$name','$director','$cast','$genre','$release',$duration,'$thumb','$plot','$another','$reviews',$critic)";` The `$this->table_name` probably isn't being interpreted as a variable.

Comment: What error it show? By the way..$cast = $_POST['cast'];`enter code here` should be $cast = $_POST['cast'];//`enter code here`

Comment: can you please tell what the error message says in short?

Comment: _'It fails'_ is not a problem description.

Comment: I've tried and it ran perfectly!!! Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

echo your old $query then copy and paste it in mysql query editor and Run it. You will what is the actual error and all query variables are blank or not.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `$this->table_name` (`name`,`director`,`cast`,`genre`,`release`,`duration`,`thumb`,`plot`,`another`,`reviews`,`critic`) "
                    . " Values ('$name','$director','$cast','$genre','$release','$duration','$thumb','$plot','$another','$reviews','$critic')";
```

Echo & check all values then Replace above query.

Answer (score 0):

`release` is a [mysql reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), so you would need to quote it in backticks.

However, you could also be sql injecting yourself. You should really switch to a prepared statement to avoid that.

You should also add error handling and display errors during development. Both mysqli and PDO can throw exceptions but you need to tell them to do that.